# Condicionales dentro de when en pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

Estoy escribiendo un código para construir una columna de un dataframe a partir de otras columnas en pyspark. El código sería el siguiente:

`sdf = sdf.withColumn('nueva_variable', when(sdf['variable2']>sdf['variable1'] & sdf['variable2']>sdf['variable3'] ,1))`

El error:
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

No comprendo por qué no es capaz de entender una condición dentro del when().
Gracias.
Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

error corregido:

sdf = sdf.withColumn('nueva_variable', when((sdf['variable2']>sdf['variable1']) & (sdf['variable2']>sdf['variable3']) ,1))

Era un tema de paréntesis.
Saludos y gracias.